# JFrame to continuously call a function to check result

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe, windowbuilder

I using Window Builder in Eclipse to create an application to continuously search for a result in SQL server. I have the function to search it. The function will return a `boolean` value (`true` or `false`). After I created a `JFrame`, how can I continuously call the function and check the return `boolean` value?

After it receive a `true`, the frame will dispose itself and call another frame.

Comment: *"the frame will dispose itself and call another frame"* See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

- Run the database code within a background thread to avoid having this code block the Swing event thread, the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread)
- But be sure to update the GUI ***on*** the Swing event thread to avoid concurrency issues/exceptions
- One way to do this is to use a SwingWorker, and run the database code within the worker's doInBackground method
- Then use the worker's publish/process method pair to update your display (JTable?) on the EDT
- For more on this, read [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
- Regarding your plan to swap JFrames -- don't. Instead refresh views, either by refreshing the data models underlying your Swing components (such as the TableModel displayed by the JTable) or swapping Swing components using a [CardLayout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). For more details, please check out [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636)